# How to remove "Europol" malware that infected Firefox in 13.04

Tags: firefox, malware

I have recently started using Ubuntu 13.04. The other day I found the Firefox browser blocked by malware. The website was from Europol and said that it had blocked the browser and that 'everything' had been encrypted.

I have uninstalled Firefox. I can still access files but I was wondering how I can eradicate this malware from my laptop. I have tried to install ClamAV, it did not work but the 2 do not have to be related.

Comment: It is probably a proxy redirect, change firefox proxy settings.

Comment: The site SAID it was from Europol - it probably wasn't. I've seen the same trick, only claiming to be from the FBI (I'm in the USA). I found it was a new window, opened by a pron site, and a trick. Unless you were running `firefox` as `root` (a very BAD idea - DO NOT DO THIS), no malware got installed. Reinstall firefox, and enjoy Ubuntu.

Comment: @waltinator you mean remove the mozilla information, the reinstallation wouldn't remove the users preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, re set Firefox did not work, Firefox was locked,
 could still access Ubuntu software centre though.

Removed Firefox via Ubuntu software centre ,Closed down, rebooted went back to software centre and reinstalled Firefox All Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think, but cannot prove anything, that the Europol virus on my PC came from a nosy neighbor. After re-installing Firefox, I have reasons to believe that there still was a link between my PC and his. I do not know how, I am too much of a lay man. A check with RKhunter, `top` and `htop` did not not come across anything suspicious.

I ended up using the `shred` command and installing Ubuntu 12.04. I think the matter is resolved now but remain vigilant. So, I am not sure if re-installing Firefox as mentioned above is sufficient.